# Pandas: Change df column values based on condition with iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take a dataframe, say

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],columns=['A','B'])

   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

Now I want to change cells in the first column.
I can do it this way:

```
df.loc[df['A'] > 1,'A'] = 10

    A  B
0   1  2
1  10  4
2  10  6
```

But what if i don't have any column names?

`df.iloc[:,0] > 1` gives me the same mask as `df['A'] > 1`

And while

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:,0] > 1,'A'] = 10
```

works perfectly fine,

using

```
df.iloc[df.iloc[:,0] > 1,1] = 10
```

on the initial df somehow return this error:

> NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

Is there a way to change specific cells using only integer indexing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) which is a mix between `.loc` and `.iloc`:

> .ix[] supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily label based, but will fall back to integer positional access unless the corresponding axis is of integer type.

In your case:

```
In [1]: df.ix[df.iloc[:,0]>1,1] =  10

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   A   B
0  1   2
1  3  10
2  5  10
```

**Edit**: `.ix` is now officially deprecated (since 0.20.0, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated))

You can use `.loc` and make use of `df.columns[i]` instead, eg. the equivalent to the above is:

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:,0]>1,df.columns[1]] =  10
```

Comment: consensus is that `ix` will go away.

Comment: (@lotrus28 the answer does contain the deprecation link since 2017)

Answer (score 2):

generate a positional index by slicing `np.arange(len(df))` with a boolean mask.

```
df.iloc[np.arange(len(df))[df.values[:, 0] > 1], 0] = 10
df
```

[image]